# Efeito hover no elemento filho com CSS

Tags: html, css3

Tenho o seguinte código, que é o menu da minha aplicação:

```html
    <div class="mainmenu-area" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
        <div class="container">
            <!--Logo-->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-menu">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img class="logo" src="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!--Logo/-->
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home-page">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#service-page">Facilidades</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#feature-page">Recursos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#price-page">Planos</a></li>
                    <!-- Isto poderá ser utilizado mais adiante <li><a href="#team-page">Team</a></li> -->
                    <li><a href="#faq-page">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li><a href="{{route('login')}}" class="login"><span class="un">Área Restrita </span><span class="ti-lock"></span></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Nele tenho um `<span>` no último elemento `<li>` ao qual eu apliquei o seguinte CSS:

```
.un {
  display: inline-block;
}

.un:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.un:hover:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Minha dúvida é: existe alguma forma de eu fazer com que este estilo da classe `un` seja disparada quando eu faça o hover no elemento pai apenas utilizando CSS?

Do jeito que eu fiz funciona quando eu passo o mouse em cima do `<a>`, porém por questões de layout gostaria que o efeito fosse disparado quando eu passo o mouse em cima do elemento pai.

Abaixo é o resultado que eu tenho no momento:

[image]

Comment: Qual elemento pai seria?

Comment: @Sam o `<li>` então teria que subir 2 níveis certo?

Comment: Ah sim, entendi agora.

Comment: Alvaro vou aproveitar para te dar uma dica, tem esse programinha de grafar tela que pode te dar uma mão, é bem levinho (2MB) e funciona muito bem, foi o que eu usei para fazer a imagem da resposta https://www.screentogif.com/?l=pt_br

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pode colocar a classe `.un` na `<li>` e usar o `:after` no `<a>` sem precisar usar `<span class="un">` em volta do link. Um nó a menos no DOM e código mais enxuto. :D

Seu `li` em vez de ficar assim:

```
<li>
   <a href="{{route('login')}}" class="login">
      <span class="un">Área Restrita</span>
      <span class="ti-lock"></span>
   </a>
</li>
```

vai ficar assim:

```
<li class="un">
   <a href="{{route('login')}}" class="login">
      Área Restrita
      <span class="ti-lock"></span>
   </a>
</li>
```

```css
body{
   background-color: black !important;
}

li{
  background-color: red;
}

.login{
   display: inline-block;
}

.un a:after {
  content: '';
  width: 0px;
  height: 1px;
  display: block;
  background: #ffffff;
  transition: 400ms;
}

.un:hover a:after {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="mainmenu-area" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
        <div class="container">
            <!--Logo-->
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-menu">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
                    <img class="logo" src="">
                </a>
            </div>
            <!--Logo/-->
            <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-menu">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#home-page">Início</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#service-page">Facilidades</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#feature-page">Recursos</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#price-page">Planos</a></li>
                    <!-- Isto poderá ser utilizado mais adiante <li><a href="#team-page">Team</a></li> -->
                    <li><a href="#faq-page">FAQ</a></li>
                    <li class="un"><a href="{{route('login')}}" class="login">Área Restrita </span><span class="ti-lock"></a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Foi exatamente isso o que eu fiz :D, obrigado @sam pela resposta

Answer (score 2):

Sim amigo é só vc colocar para "ativar" o efeito quando passar no seu `<a>` com a classe `.login`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
.login:hover .un:after {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Veja o código. Exiba em tela toda pois como está com Bootstrap não vai aparecer em telas estreitas

```css
.un {
 display: inline-block;
}

.un:after {
 content: '';
 width: 0px;
 height: 1px;
 display: block;
 background: #ff0000;
 transition: 400ms;
}

.login:hover .un:after {
 width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="mainmenu-area" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="100">
<div class="container">
 <!--Logo-->
 <div class="navbar-header">
  <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#primary-menu">
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
   <span class="icon-bar"></span>
  </button>
  <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">
   <img class="logo" src="">
  </a>
 </div>
 <!--Logo/-->
 <nav class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="primary-menu">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
   <li class="active"><a href="#home-page">Início</a></li>
   <li><a href="#service-page">Facilidades</a></li>
   <li><a href="#feature-page">Recursos</a></li>
   <li><a href="#price-page">Planos</a></li>
   <!-- Isto poderá ser utilizado mais adiante <li><a href="#team-page">Team</a></li> -->
   <li><a href="#faq-page">FAQ</a></li>
   <li><a href="{{route('login')}}" class="login"><span class="un">Área Restrita </span><span class="ti-lock"></span></a></li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</div>
```

Comment: o que eu queria fazer era quando passasse o mouse em cima do `<li>`, porém foi apenas mudar a minha classe pro elemento que eu queria que funcionou perfeitamente

Comment: @AlvaroAlves a tá o que eu entendi é que vc queria ativa no `<a>`. E como ele já tinha a classe `.login` apenas coloquei o :hover no pai para "ativar" o filho. Mas que bom que já resolveu por ai! []´s